# No error but force close

Tags: android, forceclose

I'm new to Android. I'm writing simple code to change a TextView depending on an EditText with button. I have no error in code. But when I execute it from a device, I get a force close.

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); << Error if uncomment
    //TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); << Error if uncomment

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that you do not have any *compiler errors* does not mean that there are no errors in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `findViewById()` to initialize class variables in place

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText  et;
    TextView  tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // move these here
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you think about it, the layout will only get initialized after the call to `setContentView` so you cannot find elements in that layout before it is even initialized or even set as the layout for the activity.

Comment: Why oh why oh why is this habit of calling class fields "global" invading StackOveflow?  Where did it come from?  Globals have a lifetime equal to the entire application and are accessible to all classes.  The variables in this code are class level fields.  There lifetime is equal to the declaring class.  As developers, we should strive to be accurate and this is a really annoying inaccuracy.  By allowing it to live, every noob is reading answers and going away with the idea that these are global, and so the problem spreads.

Comment: Apologies @Simon, Ive fixed my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in minde to **ALWAYS** have a look at the `LogCat` content and posted with your questions

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // You can use findViewById only once the activity has finished creating, so move the initialization to onCreate function
    EditText  et;
    TextView  tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

#### Edit:

You can open the `LogCat` like:
Clicking on the button marked by the circle (in the bottom right of Eclipse)

[image]

if you don't have it there, you can bring it up like the following:

[image]

P.S: I'm using mac but it should be the same for other OS

Answer (score -1):

Keep one thing in mind. Always give a call to `findViewById` after you have called  `setContent` otherwise it will give such errors.

Comment: what was the problem with this answer that it needed a downvote?

Comment: @Ameer: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171221/how-to-deal-with-duplicate-answers-posted-long-after-first-answers ; your answer repeats what the two other answers had already stated. That's not appreciated by some, it doesn't add value to the site.

Comment: @Mat: I didn't copy the others answers nor I transliterated what was written, I just wrote what came to my mind. But yes I couldn't see the other answers.